# I am unable to download file in asp.net MVC 3.0 razor (System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating one function in my controller which is able to download file for me. But its not working online. when i deploy my project online i am getting this error.

[image]

Please Help me for solving this problem.

> ```
>  <a id="export_excel" href='#'>
> <img id="export" src='@Url.Content("~/images/buttons/get_report.jpg")' alt="Get Report"
> ```
>
> />

In the jquery i am using this.

> $(document).ready(function () {  
>   $("#export_excel ").click(function (event) { 
>       //  $(this).attr('href', "/Home/ExportToExcelCombine?select_rows="+ $('#select_rows').val());
>           var val=$('#select_rows').val();
>           $(this).attr('href', '@Url.Action("ExportToExcelCombine", "Home")?select_rows='+val);
>        });  });

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code.  Otherwise, how can anyone help?

Comment: Please check the code mention. I have edited my quetion

Comment: It would help if you show the code for the action.  The error is a server side error, so that is where the problem is.  All the jQuery does is call that action.

Comment: Please check the code i have mentioned each and everything which i m using.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code in controller for export to excel. I am using NPOI dll for Export to excel.

> public ActionResult ExportToExcelCombine(string select_rows)
>           {
>
> var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
>
> ```
>                 string[] test = select_rows.ToString().Split(';');
>
>                 var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Summary");
>                int row_index = 0;
>                var excelnewrow = sheet.CreateRow(row_index);
>                excelnewrow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Entity Name");
>
>                row_index++;
>
>                excelnewrow = sheet.CreateRow(row_index);
>                excelnewrow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Type of Entity");
>
>                row_index++;
>                excelnewrow = sheet.CreateRow(row_index);
>                excelnewrow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Industry");
>
>                row_index++;
>                excelnewrow = sheet.CreateRow(row_index);
>                excelnewrow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Country");
>
>                row_index++;
>                excelnewrow = sheet.CreateRow(row_index);
>                excelnewrow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("");
>
>                row_index++;
>                excelnewrow = sheet.CreateRow(row_index);
>
>                HSSFCellStyle style_summary_color = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
>
>                // cell background
>                style_summary_color.FillForegroundColor = NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor.BLACK.index;
>                style_summary_color.FillPattern = HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND;
>
>                // font color
>                HSSFFont font_summary_color = workbook.CreateFont();
>                font_summary_color.Color = NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor.WHITE.index;
>                style_summary_color.SetFont(font_summary_color);
>
>                excelnewrow.RowStyle = style_summary_color;
>
>
>                excelnewrow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Facebook");
>                excelnewrow.GetCell(0).CellStyle = style_summary_color;
>
>                row_index++;
>                excelnewrow = sheet.CreateRow(row_index);
>                excelnewrow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("");
> ```
>
> using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
>                       {
>                           workbook.Write(exportData);
>
> ```
>                     string saveAsFileName = string.Format("Report-{0:d}.xls", DateTime.Now).Replace("/", "-");
>
>                     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
>                     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", saveAsFileName));
>                     Response.Clear();
>                     Response.BinaryWrite(exportData.GetBuffer());
>                     Response.End();
>                     return File(saveAsFileName, "application/vnd.ms-excel", saveAsFileName);
>                 }
> ```
>
> TempData["Message"] = "Excel report created successfully!";
>
> ```
>                 //return File(buffer, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
>
>
>                 return RedirectToAction("ExcelPackage");
> ```
>
> }

In view, i am using

> 

In jquery, i am using

> $(document).ready(function () { $("#export_excel ").click(function
>   (event) { // $(this).attr('href',
>   "/Home/ExportToExcelCombine?select_rows="+ $('#select_rows').val());
>   var val=$('#select_rows').val(); $(this).attr('href',
>   '@Url.Action("ExportToExcelCombine", "Home")?select_rows='+val); });
>   });

I am using $('#select_rows').val() for hidden field value, which changes when i select some rows in the Jtable.